# Twitter Bootstrap column definition is not properly applied to Kendo DropDown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have created a fiddle where you can see that the size of the Kendo DropDown is not set as expected.

How I have to modify the code to get the expected behaviour?

regards

HTML Code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dropdown" class="col-sm-2 control-label">DropDown</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select id="dropdown">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
                <option>Option 4</option>
                <option>Option 5</option>
                <option>Option 6</option>
                <option>Option 7</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"/> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mkeuschn/e58X8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `k-dropdown` has a fixed `width` of `12.4em`, thus the `col-sm-10` is not able to give it the width it should, simply overwrite that CSS with:

```
.k-dropdown{
    width: 100%;
}
```

That should make the dropdown fill according to the width of its parent container.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e58X8/2/)